# how to filter and auto fill data into a new sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a SourceSheet filled with rows that contains [ stuff_name , count, Price]

there are many rows that contains zero in count field
but there are some rows that contains a value like 7 for example in count field

i need to copy data[stuffname,Count, Price] from rows that have some values in count field

and push them to a certain sheet from top to down

and each time i change count in a row from SourceSheet , the result sheet update and if the value change to zero , certain row be deleted and other rows shift up

Without VBA Macro

Comment: Do you have access to the dynamic array formula FILTER?

Comment: i need to do the job automatically , after change count by costumer

Comment: This def sounds like a job for VBA. Why the limitation?

Comment: @OxefPip the dynamic array formula can be automatic in that it will update as the input range changes. I suspect doing this without VBA will mean you will have to compromise somewhere in your requirements

Comment: and how can i use dynamic array formula?

Comment: i don't want to get permission for start macro from users 
but if there is no way maybe i have to do that
now if i decide to use vba 
how can i use that for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `FILTER` function, ask @BigBen to show you the solution.

I can suggest using `INDEX` + `AGGREGATE` if you have an older excel version.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$C$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/$B$2:$B$7<>"")*ROW($B$2:$B$7),ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

Copy it right and down as needed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Documenting solution for how one would use the `FILTER` function in this scenario for those who do have access to dynamic arrays.

---

In cell `E1` you would supply the formula: `=FILTER(A1:C7,B1:B7<>"")` and the entire range will auto populate with your table. It will add and remove rows from the table as you make changes to `Column B`

[image]